# Passing generic type as generic type parameter to the generic method

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Here is original code

```cs
private static void PassGeneric(Type repositoryType)
{
    // this can be a loop where mt is changing with every iteration
    Type[] typeArgs = { mt }; // mt retrieved using some logic
    Type typedRepositoryImplementation = repositoryType.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);
}
```

Trying to make it better

```cs
private static void PassGeneric<TRepository, TModel>()
    where TRepository : IRepository<TModel> where TModel : class
{

    Type[] typeArgs = { mt }; 
    Type repositoryType = typeof(TDataRepository)
    Type typedRepositoryImplementation = repositoryType.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);

}
```

With the second version I need now to do this - instead of obtaining the list of types inside the method, I need a wrapping method in which I will iterate

```cs
private static void PassGeneric<TRepository, TModel>()
{ . . . . . }

private static void IterateGeneric()
{
    IEnumerable<(Type, Type)> typeList = GetList();
    foreach(var t in typeList)
    {

        PassGeneric<??, ??>() <-- I am glitching right here
    }   
}
```

I am going into wrong direction with this? Should I stick to `PassGeneric(Type repositoryType)`?

Comment: Generally you should stick to the reflection Type if you don't have an actual type parameter.

Comment: surely `Type[] typeArgs = { t.Item1, t.Item2 };` - the rest is similar to your original code